# onmouseover and onmouseout don't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm trying to change a CSS attribute by using a java-script function so This code is not working in firefox / works with Safari/Chrome

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
         #hide {
            display: none ;
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div onmouseover="document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'compact';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';" >
            Move Over Mouse here
         </div>
         <div id="hide"> THIS IS HIDDEN TEXT</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any Ideas ?!

Comment: Where did you get `compact` from? It doesn't exactly get used very often.

Answer (score 2):

Try display style 'inline' rather than 'compact'.

Comment: @Jim Well, it's a DIV, so `'block'` would be the proper value here.

Comment: Good point. In my defense trying 'inline' would at least reveal if that was the problem. I'd never encountered the 'compact' type before, there's not much on the net about it but it does seem to exist in Chrome at least, although I can't tell what it does.

Comment: Oh great! both of 'block' and 'inline' works, but why "compact" was working on other browsers and firefox not ?!

Comment: @Jim The best source to look for info is obviously the standard. The `display` property is defined in the CSS Basic Box Model module. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#the-lsquo There are 21 predefined values for that property, and `'compact'` *is* one of them.

Comment: @Jim Btw, you can use my [W3 Viewer](http://w3viewer.com) whenever you need to look up something in the standards `:)`

Comment: @Waseem Firefox does not support the `'compact'` value. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

Comment: @Šime Vidas many thanks for the info, on this occasion we see here how the HTML as practiced differs from the standard as defined. But this is what I love about answering questions on Stack Overflow, you never know what you'll learn.

Comment: Viewer doesn't seem to work in the latest Chromium build :/ dang

Comment: @raidfive That's true. I tried in Chromium 12.0.721.0 and got a ReferenceError. It appears that I shot myself in the foot by early adopting strict-mode `:)`. I've removed the `"use strict;"` directive from my code, it works in Chromium now...